# Node.js: How to implement a simple and functional Mutex mechanism to avoid racing conditions that bypass the guard statement in simultaneous actions

Tags: node.js, multithreading, locking, race-condition

In the following class, the `_busy` field acts as a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)); but, *in "simultaneous" situations it fails to guard!*

```
class Task {
    _busy = false;

    async run(s) {
        try {
            if (this._busy)
                return;
            this._busy = true;
            await payload();
        } finally {
            this._busy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The sole purpose of the `run()` is to execute the `payload()` **exclusively**, *denying all the other invocations while it's still being carried on*. In other words, when "any" of the invocations reach to to the `run()` method, I want it to only allow the first one to go through and lock it down (denying all the others) until it's done with its payload; "finally", it opens up once it's done.

In the implementation above, the racing condition do occur by invoking the `run()` method simultaneously through various parts of the app. Some of the invocations (more than 1) make it past through the "guarding" `if` statement, since none of them are yet reached to the `this._busy = true` to lock it down (they get past simultaneously). So, the current implementation doesn't cut it!

I just want to deny the simultaneous invocations while one of them is already being carried out. I'm looking for a simple solution to only resolve this issue. I've designated the [async-mutex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex) library as a last resort!

So, how to implement a *simple* "locking" mechanism to avoid racing conditions that bypass the guard statement in simultaneous actions?

---

For more clarification, as per the comments below, the following is almost the actual `Task` class (without the irrelevant).

```
class Task {
    _cb;
    _busy = false;
    _count = 0;

    constructor(cb) {
        this._cb = cb;
    }

    async run(params = []) {
        try {
            if (this._busy)
                return;
            this._busy = true;
            this._count++;
            if (this._count > 1) {
                console.log('Race condition!', 'count:', this._count);
                this._count--;
                return;
            }
            await this._cb(...params);
        } catch (err) {
            await someLoggingRoutine();
        } finally {
            this._busy = false;
            this._count--;
        }
    }
}
```

I do encounter with the `Race condition!` log. Also, all the task instances are local to a simple driver file (the instances are not passed down to any other function, they only wander as local instances in a single function.) They are created in the following form:

```
const t1 = new Task(async () => { await doSth1(); /*...*/ });
const t2 = new Task(async () => { await doSth2(); /*...*/ });
const t3 = new Task(async () => { await doSth3(); /*...*/ });
// ...
```

I do call them in the various library events, some of which happen concurrently and causing the "race condition" issue; e.g.:

```
someLib.on('some-event', async function() { /*...*/ t1.run().then(); /*...*/ });
anotherLib.on('event-2', async function() { /*...*/ t1.run().then(); /*...*/ });
```

Comment: Unless you are using worker threads, there is no multithreading in javascript and your described scenario can't happen.

Comment: I use some libraries (like database and other network libraries) that do use worker threads internally. I **do** encounter with racing condition in my actual app!

Comment: I actually find that hard to believe for various reasons. Are you entirely sure, all your different invocations are using the very same instance of your `Task` class? Because, of course each new instance of the `Task` class will allow one additional "parallel" execution of the `payload()`

Comment: Even if some of your used libraries use worker thread internally, either those libraries would be needed to run your tasks on those workerthreads, or you yourself must create multiple threads to run your tasks. And even then it seems very unlikely (eventough not impossible at a certain workload) to me, that two workerthreads are running so simulantiously that your described scenario would happen. Let alone the problem of shared memory between workerthreads which isn't so easy to achieve ...

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that a same instance of the `Task` is involved and there's no misunderstanding here (the respective code is very small and the certainty is easily conformable by a simple eyeballing!) Also, the `payload()` here is just a placeholder. The "payload" is actually a callback function assigned in the constructor in the actual class (the provided code is just a simplification to convey the point I'm trying to say.)

Comment: hm, when you say "callback function" are you sure that thing returns a promise, so that it is awaitable? Or in other words, are you sure, your `payload()` is already finished, when you reach the `finally` block? Mixing callbacks any promises can be challenging and one little mistake causes a promise to resolve prematurely ...

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure that the stored callback functions are all marked as `async`, and all of them have a `getConnection()` call that need to be `await`ed; thus the pretense of the `async` keyword is enforced.

Comment: The way node works, there are three situations where your code could lead to the described behavior. 1) `await payload()` resolves prematurely. 2) there are different instances of `Task` involved or 3) that code is running on different worker threads which pretty much directly leads to 2) ...

Comment: I've updated the post, please check it out. I do encounter with the `Race condition!` log. Also, all the task instances are local variables that are not passed to any function, they only live in a simple driver file and are created in the following form: `const t1 = new Task(async () => { await onSth(); /*...*/ });` I do call them in the various library events, e.g.: `t1.run().then();`

Comment: @derpirscher After all these, I hope you believe _I do encounter with racing condition!_ and hopefully to the community (including you) helping me out of this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh god, now I see it. How could I have missed this so long! Here is your implemenation:

```
async run() {
   try {
      if (this._busy)
         return;
      ...
   } finally {
      this._busy = false;
   }
}
```

As per [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#syntax):

> *The Statements in the `finally` block are executed before control flow exits the `try...catch...finally` construct.* These statements execute regardless of whether an exception was thrown or caught.

Thus, when it's busy and the flow reaches the guarding `if`, and then,  logically encounters the `return` statement. The `return` statement causes the flow to exit the `try...catch...finally` construct; thus, as per the documentations, the statements in the `finally` block are executed whatsoever: setting the `this._busy = false;`, opening the thing up!

---

So, the first call of `run()` sets `this._busy` as being `true`; then enters the critical section with its longrunning callback. While this callback is running, just another event causes the `run()` to be invoked. This second call is rationally blocked from entering the critical section by the guarding `if` statement:

```
if (this._busy) return;
```

Encountering the `return` statement to exit the function (and thus exiting the `try...catch...finally` construct) causes the statements in the `finally` block to be executed; thus, `this._busy = false` resets the flag, even though the first callback is still running! Now suppose a third call to the `run()` from yet another event is invoked! Since `this._busy` is just set to `false`, the flow happily enters the critical section again, even though the first callback is still running! In turn, it sets `this._busy` back to `true`. In the meantime, the first callback finishes, and reaches the `finally` block, where it set `this._busy = false` again; even though the other callback is still running. So the next call to `run()` can enter the critical section again with no problems... And so on and so forth...

So to resolve the issue, *the check for the critical section should be **outside** of the `try` block:*

```
async run() {
   if (this._busy) return;
   this._busy = true;

   try { ... }
   finally {
      this._busy = false; 
   }
}
```

Comment: This is genius! You've nailed it; I truly appreciate it, Thank you.